# Get all data of specific fields

Tags: elasticsearch, bigdata

I 'am using Elastic search 5.1.1,how to get all data specified for these below  fields **(FeatureValue,FeatureName)**

sample document

```
 {
             "_index": "rawdata",
             "_type": "feed",
             "_id": "591031",
             "_score": 1,
             "_source": {
                "sourceproductname": "1-5-Size Relays",
                "zmfrid": 4,
                "sourcetitle": null,
                "featurename": "Coil Magnetic System",
                "localsourcepath": null,
                "sourcingdate": "2017-01-08T22:00:00.000Z",
                "migrationstatus": 3,
                "featrueunit": null,
                "inputkeyword": null,
                "@version": "1",
                "sourcetype": "DirectFeed",
                "id": 591031,
                "sourceid": 674,
                "partdataid": null,
                "partid": null,
                "featurecondition": null,
                "sourcingstatus": null,
                "sourcetaxonomypath": "1-5-Size Relays",
                "sourcename": "CrunchBase                                       ",
                "tags": [],
                "sourceurl": "N/A",
                "@timestamp": "2017-01-10T11:51:54.095Z",
                "featurevalue": "Non-Polarized, Monostable",
                "mfr": "feed",
                "partdataattributeid": null,
                "supplierfamily": "null",
                "partnumber": "4-1617072-5"
             }
          }
```

I tried this

```
POST /rawdata/feed/_search?pretty=true
{
"_source": ["FeatureValue", "FeatureName"],
"query": {
"match_all":{}
}
}
```

sample result

```
  {
     "took": 4,
     "timed_out": false,
     "_shards": {
     "total": 5,
     "successful": 5,
     "failed": 0
     },
     "hits": {
     "total": 386424,
     "max_score": 1,
     "hits": [
     {
     "_index": "rawdata",
     "_type": "feed",
     "_id": "591031",
     "_score": 1,
     "_source": {}
     }
```

Comment: Can you show a sample document you have in your index?

Comment: @Val I edited the post with the sample document

Comment: Ok, then you simply need to lowercase the field names in the source filter since they are lowercased in your documents.

Comment: OK you are right it worked well ,thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to lowercase the field names in the source filter since they are lowercased in your documents

```
POST /rawdata/feed/_search?pretty=true
{
  "_source": ["featurevalue", "featurename"],       <--- change this
  "query": {
    "match_all":{}
  }
}
```